# List existing LVM2 tags

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

Adding tags to LVM volumes and showing volumes that possess that tag is easy and works like a charm; but somehow I can't find a way to list all tags in use, or to show tags that apply to a specific volume. `lvdisplay -v` doesn't give me details on tags, neither `lvs` seems to have any option for that. (I am using CentOS 5.4.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Showing tags that belong to a specific volume:

```
# lvchange --addtag @RootFS /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
Logical volume "LogVol00" changed

# lvs -o lv_tags /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
  LV Tags
  RootFS

# lvs -o lv_tags /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01
  LV Tags
```

You can easily script getting the active tags for a specific volume that way.

If you parse the output of the lvs command, and run the logical volumes through the command I used above, you'll be able to grep, sed and awk your way to a list of all tags in use.

Physical volumes and volume groups have commands that are similar to the above:

```
# pvs -o pv_tags /dev/sda2
  PV Tags

# vgs -o vg_tags /dev/VolGroup00
  VG Tags
```

[Here's a Red Hat KB article about this](http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-15348)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly what I was searching for :)